# How to create a temporary sql table with name passed as a parameter?

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, temp-tables, sonarlint

I want to create a temporary sql table with a dynamic table name.

```
string temporaryTableName = $"TempTable_{Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", string.Empty)}";
                         //.....
string createTempTableQuery = $"CREATE TABLE #{temporaryTableName} (";

createTempTableQuery +=
                            "[StockDetailsKey][bigint] IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL, " +
                            "[ClientKey][int] NULL, " +                            
                            "[AddedOn] [datetime] NULL, " +
                            "[ModifiedOn] [datetime] NULL ";

createTempTableQuery += ")";
sqlCommand.CommandText = createTempTableQuery;

sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The code works fine but Sonar doesn't like it saying that I should parameterize that line.

Comment: Note that `Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", string.Empty);` can be rewritten as `Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N")`, and `$"TempTable_{Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", string.Empty)}"` -> `$"TempTable_{Guid.NewGuid():N}"`

Comment: @Alexa  I have deleted my answer, as It was wrong and was not helpful at all. please refer  Marc Gravell answer below. and I am sorry for providing you wrong information, I apologise

Answer (score 1):

Table names **cannot be parameterized** (nor can columns, schemas, etc) - they are the fundamental structure of the query itself, not values. In another answer you have (via comments) been directed to use `#@temporaryTableName` and a `@temporaryTableName` parameter, but this **does not do what you think**; it is not parameterized - it is simply a temporary table *called literally `@temporaryTableName`* (it surprises me that this is legal, but it is). You can verify this simply by *not declaring such a parameter / variable* - for example:

```sql
create table #@foo (id int not null);
select * from #@foo;
drop table #@foo;
```

the above works fine, despite `@foo` not being declared or having a value.

---

However, you probably *don't need to do what you're trying to do*. There are three kinds of temporary table:

1. `@tables` - table variables - these are scoped to a single command / stored-procedure call / etc, and never escape - you would never need to worry about name collisions, even for a recursive call
2. `#tables` - temporary tables - these are connection-specific, and persist between operations on the same connection; because they are connection-specific, you don't need to worry about collisions between different connections, so there shouldn't usually be a need to have different names unless you're doing something *very* weird
3. `##tables` - global temporary tables - these are shared between connections, and aren't really "temporary" in any sense other than the name (and the DB in which the data is stored); almost never useful

So: we're almost certainly really talking about option 1 or option 2; if the data is intended to last between multiple operations, you need a `#table`, otherwise you need a `@table` - so: *just do that*:

```sql
CREATE TABLE #MeaningfulName(...)";
```

or

```sql
declare @MeaningfulName table(...);
```

The RDBMS will deal with the collision side of things for you, meaning that you *don't need* to randomize the name. The simple fact that the name is meaningful and specific: is sufficient.

---

If for some reason that isn't sufficient (and you need multiple overlapping connection-scoped tables representing different data payloads), then: you'll have to concatenate a table name into your query, but: that does not represent a SQL injection attack vector as long as *only your code* can influence the name; the `temporaryTableName` shown in your post is not vulnerable, for example - so you would concatenate that name exactly like you already are. So: in that rare example, just nod to the tool that flagged a warning and thank it for bringing it to your attention, and then simply override/suppress/ignore that specific warning instance, recording that you've inspected the code, that it is intentional and does not involve external data, and is considered "safe".

---

As a side-note: you are allocating a bunch of unnecessary temporary strings *and* making the code harder to read than is necessary; consider:

```cs
string createTempTableQuery = @$"CREATE TABLE #{temporaryTableName} (
    [StockDetailsKey] bigint IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [ClientKey] int NULL,
    [AddedOn] datetime NULL,
    [ModifiedOn] datetime NULL
);";
```

(I also doubt that a `#table` with an `IDENTITY(1, 1)` requires `bigint`, but...)

Comment: May I know how to pass the dynamic name to the table then? that is `TempTable_{Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", string.Empty)}` as per OP's requirement

Comment: @viveknuna you would have to just concatenate the data, as shown in the original post; I added a paragraph

Comment: but it will not fix the Sonar error. so we have to live with it?

Comment: @viveknuna it would not fix the sonar *false positive*; so you look at the sonar documentation for how to suppress a false positive